# Transposing the list

Tags: python, numpy, transpose

I have the following list:

```
y = [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

I would like to transpose it and have it in the following form:

```
[[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]]
```

When I did `numpy.transpose(y)`, I got the following:

```
[[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Y is already in that form. Its a list of lists. Transpose did it correctly and took the transpose. Unless Im missing something

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I mean converting it from a "horizontal" form into a "vertical" form

Comment: `np.asarray(y)`?

Comment: @Piinthesky Exactly! This is what I wanted. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

```
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

is exactly the same as this form:

```
[[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]]
```

You had a matrix with 8 rows and 1 column. Transposition executed on the matrix converted it to a matrix with just 1 row and 8 columns, so the output was correct.

Comment: do the "commas" matter? The appear in the first form, but not in the second

Comment: The second form is not a valid python code (it will try to take the first element of the first element of the first element... of the list containing just integer 0). The form with commas is how you represent the vertical matrix in python (unless you use some libraries you didn't mention in your question that could parse it).

Answer (score 0):

If `y` is a list of lists, it displays as a single line

```
In [1]: y = [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
In [2]: y
Out[2]: [[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
In [3]: print(y)
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

You could of course do a line by line print

```
In [4]: for i in y: print(i)
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

If I make an array from it, I get a 2d (n,1) array

```
In [5]: Y = np.array(y)
In [6]: Y
Out[6]: 
array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])
In [7]: print(Y)
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

The array display does show rows and columns.  Note that array print does not include commas (but its repr does).

If I transpose it, I get a (1,n) array, which displays as 1 line

```
In [8]: Y.T
Out[8]: array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

There 3 different things that you may be confusing - the list, its print or string representation, and an array constructed from the list (and its print).

There is a list version of 'transpose':

```
In [9]: list(zip(*y))
Out[9]: [(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

---

A longer list of lists may display as you want (if it doesn't neatly fit one line):

```
In [20]: z=[[i] for i in range(15)]
In [21]: z
Out[21]: 
[[0],
 [1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [4],
 [5],
 [6],
 [7],
 [8],
 [9],
 [10],
 [11],
 [12],
 [13],
 [14]]
```

Except - that's an `ipython` pretty print action.  In a plain `python` 
shell

```
>>> [[i] for i in range(15)]
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14]]
```

Which just emphasizes my point - there's a difference between a list and its print representation.

There is a `pprint.pprint` (pretty print) that behaves more like `ipython`, switching to row prints when the list gets too long.